# How do I get my funds from bitstamp into my wallet?

Tags: wallet, address, multibit, bitstamp

Hi I am using multibit as my bitcoin wallet.  I will be using money gram to put money into my account.  I dont know how to buy bitcoins for myself.

On multibit it says you can send coins to someone or request them but it doesn't say to yourself.  I don't want to send them to anyone else, just me.  I am using bitinstant to transfer funds into bitstamp, but where do I get the wallet address?

Where do I enter the amount I want in bitcoins on bitinstant? And how do I get my funds from bitstamp into my wallet?  Which one do I use first and what is the address I type into the website I am buying items off of so they can withdraw them from my account?

I really need help with buying bitcoins for myself and where I find the address and that I do when I go to the money gram?  Where is the address found?  And do I need to use bitstamp?

Is there an easier way to do this because I'm finding it really hard.  If there is a quicker easier software or website or wallet to use please let me know!

Edit:
Also, where do I enter the amount of funds I'm going to put into the moneygram on Bitstamp, do I use Bitinstant for that? What do I do when I get to the moneygram? Do I enter the address? Can someone tell me an easier process including whichever websites you all use and in what order and how you actually retrieve the money to use online?

Comment: Hi willowstarr! Please don't use all caps in your question. It is very hard to read and is usually interpreted as someone shouting. I will change the subject line now but the rest needs to be cleaned up too!

Comment: Paragraphs would really help too.

Comment: Have you read the Help page for MultiBit? https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_receivingBitcoin.html

Answer (score 2):

Login to Bitstamp account >> Deposit >> Bitcoin >> here is your Bitstamp deposit address.

To transfer bitcoins to your Multibit wallet, again Login to Bitstamp account >> Withdrawal >> Bitcoin >>  here you can enter your Multibit wallet address and bitcoin amount.

Comment: Thank you so much!! sorry for using all caps I wasn't paying attention. I thought it was a long process using multiple websites so I was frustrated! When using money gram, do I enter Bitstamp deposit address?